# Storing the contents in a String variable rather than a file

Tags: java

I have a process of XML transform in which I am writing the output transformed XML to a file. But instead of storing it in a file I want to store it in a string variable. I have created a string variable, please advise how can I store the generated XML in a string variable (msgxml instead of writing a file).

```
String msgxml;  

System.setProperty("javax.xml.transform.TransformerFactory",
                "org.apache.xalan.processor.TransformerFactoryImpl"); 

FileInputStream xml = new FileInputStream(xmlInput);
FileInputStream xsl = new FileInputStream(xslInput);
FileOutputStream os = new FileOutputStream(outputXmlFile);

TransformerFactory tFactory = TransformerFactory.newInstance();
// Use the TransformerFactory to process the stylesheet source and produce a Transformer 
StreamSource styleSource = new StreamSource(xsl);
Transformer transformer = tFactory.newTransformer(styleSource);


StreamSource xmlSource = new StreamSource(xml);
StreamResult result = new StreamResult(os);

//here we are storing it in a file , 
try {
    transformer.transform(xmlSource, result);
} catch (TransformerException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: If `StreamResult` can accept a `java.io.Writer` then a possible solution would be to use a [`java.io.StringWriter`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/StringWriter.html).

Answer (score 1):

One way is to use an `ByteArrayOutputStream` instead of a `FileOutputStream`:

```
ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
TransformerFactory tFactory = TransformerFactory.newInstance();

...

StreamSource xmlSource = new StreamSource(xml);
StreamResult result = new StreamResult(baos);  // write to the byte array stream

//here we are storing it in a file , 
try {
    transformer.transform(xmlSource, result);
}
...

msgxml = baos.toString("UTF-8");  // get contents of stream using UTF-8 encoding
```

Another solution is to use a [`java.io.StringWriter`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/StringWriter.html):

```
StringWriter stringWriter = new StringWriter();
StreamResult result = new StreamResult(stringWriter);

...

msgxml = stringWriter.toString();
```

Comment: Your first example doesn't consider encoding. The transformer will generate output using UTF-8, the `toString()` function uses the default encoding (which may not be UTF-8). You second example is the correct one.